# iPad 2 downloaded iOS 6 trouble with downloading apps

Tags: ios

I have upgraded to iOS 6 now every time I try to download a new app it asks my password and then asks me to set up security questions when I finish and hit one it tells me it timed out. I have tried the reset in Settings > General. This did not resolve the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Set up your Security Questions and answers online at https://appleid.apple.com . Applies to the App Store too - it's all one.